# Selenium webdriver Java how to wait until a link is present

Tags: java, automation, selenium-webdriver, sleep, wait

I have a link that I press and then it runs some JS and a new link is generated on the page which has the text "View report"

How can I wait on the page until this link is present and clickable, or timeout if its not displayed in say five minutes?

I have seen this question asked a few times and tried some of the solutions but can't get any to work.

I've even tried a rubbish way of just waiting for a minute but sometimes the link takes longer to appear so it fails.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

    `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("View report")));`

Comment: Correct except for the spelling of some methods/attributes:
element = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, link_text)))